# Highlight second occurrence of a character within a word

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I tried solving the below problem but could not seem to find solution. I basically wanted [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to highlight the second matching character in a certain word.

For example: my pattern is: `b|l`

> echo "bold" | grep '[bl]' --> **b**o**l**d (b and l in bold)

What I wanted to see was bo**l**d (l in bold)

Comment: Since `grep` is used to detect matching lines, it's not really clear why it matters if it matches the first or the second occurrence of a character.  Or are you saying, you only want to match the line if there is more than one occurrence of the character.

Comment: @MikeRyan: Thanks for your input. I only want to match a specific character. If a word contains two characters that match my pattern, grep should highlight the 2nd one only. 

Thanks so much for that command - pfnuesel

Comment: I deleted my first comment, rather try this one: `echo "bold" | grep '[bl]' | egrep 'l|$'`

Comment: both worked great. But I still dont get it. Why would you use l|$?

Comment: What do you mean by highlight?  `grep` doesn't highlight.  It looks at an incoming line, and processes as follows:  if (line matches reg. exp.) { print line}      It does that for every line in your input.

Comment: [tag:grep] highlights with e.g. the option `--color=auto`. I elevated my comment to an answer but have one more question: What happens if your second match is *not* found?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) twice:

```
echo "bold" | grep '[bl]' | egrep 'l|$'
```

The first [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) greps everything you want, the second one greps all the lines with an `l` and highlights them, but also greps everything else (`$` is the end of a line), so you don't lose any matches.

This gives:

```
echo "bold" | grep '[bl]' | egrep 'l|$'
```

> bo**l**d

```
echo "hold" | grep '[bl]' | egrep 'l|$'
```

> ho**l**d

```
echo "bond" | grep '[bl]' | egrep 'l|$'
```

> bond

Note that you need to enable highlighting by e.g. `grep --color=auto` for this to make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. It worked great. But when I put these inside a loop, the words were just in white..not showing any matching characters.@@

Comment: You need to post your code, otherwise it's impossible to understand what's going on.

Comment: I tried testing to see if it worked within a loop, but turned out it did not.

    while read line; do
        for word in ${line}; do
                   printf "\r\033[0K${word}" | grep '[ae]'
            sleep 0.5
        done
    done < test

My test file has this line: 

> abe thin thic h coop bot

Basically what I'm doing here is print 1 word at a time and show a matching character in red

Comment: It works for me. Do you use grep --color=auto? Or how do you highlight your matches?